# Stylesheet url_for code for image in a parallel folder

Tags: python, css, flask

I am attempting to build a website using Flask.  I am using Python 3.9  I have the following directory tree:

```
environment/
    main.py
    app.yaml
    requirements.txt

    Templates/
        base.html      #base template
        index.html     #extends base.html

    Static/
        css/
            main.css
        images/
            favicon.ico
            bckgrnd.jpg
        fonts/
            Carolingian.ttf
            Latin.ttf
```

Here is the code in main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have been trying to set the background image for my website.  In "main.py", I have imported url_for, and I know that it works because I can get it to work for my favicon, which is coded in the HEAD section of the base.html template.  Additionally, I have tested my background image in the base.html template with the code:

```
<BODY style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='/images/bckgrnd.jpg') }})">
```

This code works successfully.  However, I would prefer to move this styling to my stylesheet.  I also expect to run into the same problem when I implement my custom fonts, which are essential to the correct functioning of the webapp.  I have tried to implement the same code in the stylesheet:

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(180,160,120);
  background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='/images/bckgrnd.jpg') }});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

However, the background does not appear (the rest of my stylesheet is working fine, including the background color, so no problems there).  My terminal informs me that it is not looking for bckgrnd.jpg in the images folder, but in the css folder:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2021 10:19:56] "GET /static/css/bckgrnd.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I don't understand why it would look in the css folder for the image, rather than in the images folder or some subfolder of css called images (which doesn't exist), since I have clearly indicated that the file is in a folder called images, but I suspect that the reason why the code works in the base.html template inside the BODY tag but not in the stylesheet might be because the stylesheet is already in the static folder (and furthermore, within a subfolder of the static folder), while the base.html template is outside the static folder.

I have attempted to emmend the code to look in a parent folder:

```
body {
  background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='/../images/bckgrnd.jpg') }};
  }
```

But this code makes no difference to either the appearance of the webpage or the information in the termincal.  It is still looking for the file in the css folder and not the images folder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already in `static` when you're in the CSS file. So why not write the path directly:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/static/images/bckgrnd.jpg');
}
```

You should also try  `url({{ url_for('static', filename='images/bckgrnd.jpg') }});`. Notice the missing forward slash in front of images. If that doesn't work it means Jinja is used only on the file that's used as input in flask's render_template.

Comment: I have had no success writing the path directly, as suggested.  Nor has it helped to remove the leading slash before the filename path.  I still do not set he background image, and the terminal continues to look in the css folder.

Comment: I actually tried your example. It works very well just as I said - writing the path directly. Also, when using directly in the template the variant with the forward slash at the beginning, Flask raises a 308 error. It handles the error by itself, but at the cost of an additional request. What I did in the template that you probably didn't do, was loading the stylesheet of course. Did you write `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }} "/>` in the `<head>` section of index.html?

Comment: Also, when running the app via `flask run` with the stylesheet, I have 3 requests with status 200. One corresponding to the `/` path, one for `/static/css/main.css` and another one for `/static/images/<image>.jpg`.  Do you have those 3 requests as well?

Comment: Actually, I take it back.  Your solution has worked for me as well.  I just didn't realize it for quite a while until I entered the inspector in Chrome and discovered that the changes that I was making to my stylesheet were not being loaded because Chrome was pulling up a cached stylesheet.  I entered the paths directly in the stylesheet as you suggested, then cleared my Chrome cache, and lo and behold, it worked correctly.  Thank you for your help!